# SEO for a website where data comes from API after few seconds

Tags: seo

I've created a website which is fully implemented on Angular and Webservice based but I've few doubts that site HTML is loaded immediately but its data comes from Angular Ajax call so it takes few seconds and when google bots visit it they might not get data so is there any issue with SEO or something I've some doubt on it.

Comment: Have you tried using Fetch as Google in the Search Console (Webmaster Tools) to see how your page loads? You will want to Fetch and Render. As well you can try using Google speed test. Page speed is important. You may want to pay particular attention to this.

Comment: My site uses react.js and loads most of the content asynchronously. Google seems to have no problem indexing it and finding the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this setup is that two requests are made to the server. One to load the initial HTML and one to load the actual data through AJAX. This alone can be enough to create a negative impact on SEO especially if all of the required content to be presented on the screen requires AJAX.

Also you mentioned your site takes a few seconds to load. This is also bad for SEO. If I'm not mistaken, people generally go away from a website if it takes longer than about 2 seconds to load, and anything that takes over 1.5 seconds to load is considered "slow" by google.

If you must use your setup, then at least have most of the content you want users to read loaded and ready before the AJAX code is executed.

Comment: Thanks @Mike I think I should change something in codes :)